# How can I make a ngrx effects that gets the current state of email and send that to a AuthApiService if it succedes?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am using Angular 16 with Google Identity and google one tap, to make users being able to login:
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview

Currently I am working on the logout feature of the application, where I want to revoke the token in my .net backend. 
To do that I want to dispatch an action when the user does that.

This is what I have tried:

This is revokeToken() from AuthApiService, where I send the information to the backend, which use the email (a string) to logout the user. It takes in a string email, which it should get when I dispatch the action.

```
revokeToken(email: string) {
    const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.delete(`api/v1/Auth/RevokeToken/` + email, { headers: header, withCredentials: true });
}
```

Therefore, I have created actions:

```
import { createActionGroup, emptyProps, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

export const AuthActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Auth',
  events: {
    'Logout Init': emptyProps(),
    'Logout Success': emptyProps(),
    'Logout Failed': props<{ error: HttpErrorResponse }>(),
  },
});
```

and reducers to implement this:

```
import { createFeature, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AuthActions } from './auth.actions';
import { LoadingState } from '../../shared/models/loading-state.model';

export interface AuthState {
  token: string;
  email: string;
  fullName: string;
}

export const initialState: AuthState = {
  token: '',
  email: '',
  fullName: '',
};

export const authFeature = createFeature({
  name: 'auth',
  reducer: createReducer(
    initialState,

    on(AuthActions.logoutInit, (state) => ({
      ...state,
      ...LoadingState.loading(),
    })),
    on(AuthActions.logoutSuccess, (state) => ({
      ...state,
      token: '',
      email: '',
      fullName: '',
      ...LoadingState.loaded(),
    })),
    on(AuthActions.logoutFailed, (state, { error }) => ({
      ...state,
      ...LoadingState.failed(error),
    })),
  )
})
```

and I now need the effect. This is what I have tried:

```
revokeTokenAtLogout$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.logoutInit),
    concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(selectEmail)),
    map(([action, email]) => {
      this.authApiService.revokeToken(email).pipe(
        AuthActions.logoutSuccess(),
        catchError(error => of(AuthActions.logoutFailed({error})))
      )
    })
   )
})
```

Which I know does not work.

I know what it should do though.

1. It must listen on logoutInit,
2. then get the current state of email from the store,
3. then give that to the revokeToken as we call it,
4. if it succeedes, logout and navigate back to the login screen.
5. if it fails, return the logoutFailed action.

I am hopelessy stuck with it and been looking at it for days..

What I need help with is how to implement the effect correctly, so that it works as intended.
Can anybody help me with this?

**EDIT:**
**The solution for this problem is:**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
  constructor(
    private readonly actions$: Actions,
    private readonly store: Store,
    private readonly authApiService: AuthApiService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

  revokeTokenAtLogout$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.logoutInit),
      concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(selectEmail)),
      switchMap(([, email]) =>
        this.authApiService.revokeToken(email).pipe(
          map(() => AuthActions.logoutSuccess()),
          catchError(error => of(AuthActions.logoutFailed({ error })))
        ),
      ),
    );
  });

  logoutNavigate$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.logoutSuccess),
      tap(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['login']).then(() => window.location.reload());
      })
    );
  }, { dispatch: false })
}
```

Comment: In the effects, what does this line do: `AuthActions.logoutSuccess()`?

Comment: It should use the action logoutSuccess.
Since I don't know how to make effects, that's why I need help.
I'm completely stuck with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asking questions please define "does not work".
Because, to me, the code matches the description:

```
revokeTokenAtLogout$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
// ✅ It must listen on logoutInit,
    ofType(AuthActions.logoutInit),
// ✅ then get the current state of email from the store,    concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(selectEmail)),
    map(([action, email]) => {
// ✅ then give that to the revokeToken as we call it,
      this.authApiService.revokeToken(email).pipe(
// ✅ if it succeedes, logout and navigate back to the login screen., 
// ⚠️ but wrap it in a `map`
        map(() => AuthActions.logoutSuccess()),
// ✅ if it fails, return the logoutFailed action.
        catchError(error => of(AuthActions.logoutFailed({error})))
      )
    })
   )
})
```

What we don't see but can affect the outcome:

- the `email` property is not set to a value
- the logic behind the `LoadingState.abc()` methods in the reducer
- the http response
- how the store is registered

Comment: Ahh okay thanks, then it was basically only because I was missing the map wrapped around the second to last line, that it was not working out for me. I actually did figure it out myself before your answer. However, it is nice to hear some feedback, that my solution was almost right, in the first place, since I'm new to Angular and very new to ngrx. So, that fixed my problem. Thanks! I also created an effect for navigating the user back.